# handling didSelectRowatindexPath for two tableViews in one ViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have two table views in same view controller. I am displaying authors in top table view. When I select an author the corresponding books of author should be displayed in bottom table view (list of books).

How can I handle `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` for both these table views in my single view controller.

Can any one help me out how to achieve this task.

Comment: Hey don't downvote this. The question was not written well but I edited it and I think I also added a decent answer. This is a real problem people encounter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function prototype for that `UITableViewDelegate` method is as follows:

> `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)`

That first argument is the `UITableView` in which the row was selected. So in your implementation you can simply do something like:

```
// Assuming you have two instances in your viewcontroller like this
var tableViewOne: UITableView!
var tableViewTwo: UITableView!

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if tableView == tableViewOne {
        // User selected a row in tableviewOne
    } else if tableView == tableViewTwo {
        // User selected a row in tableviewTwo
    }
}
```

If your code gets messy because you combine the logic for two `UITableViewDelegate`s into one viewcontroller, then you can also create separate objects of course.

```
class FirstTableViewDelegate: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        // User selected a row in tableviewOne
    }
}

class SecondTableViewDelegate: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        // User selected a row in tableviewTwo
    }
}

class YourViewController: UITableViewController {
    var firstDelegate: FirstTableViewDelegate!
    var secondDelegate: SecondTableViewDelegate!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        firstDelegate = FirstTableViewDelegate()
        tableViewOne.delegate = firstDelegate

        secondDelegate = SecondTableViewDelegate()
        tableViewTwo.delegate = secondDelegate
    }
}
```

Note that you *must* keep the delegates in instance variables in your own `UIViewController`. If you just create them locally or only assign them to the `UITableView` then they will be deallocated immediately since the delegate is a `weak` reference.

Comment: Does that mean you solved your tableview puzzle? :-)

Comment: Add the above code to the question please. I can't read it. It looks wrong that you de queue cells in the didSelectRow handler.